# Postgres to_tsvector VS ::tsvector

Tags: postgresql

I don't really understand the difference between `to_tsvector` and `::tsvector` in Postgres. I read the documentation on `to_tsvector`[here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-textsearch.html), but there doesn't seem to be any documentation for the other, `::tsvector` - that's a bit problematic. It is mentioned [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/datatype-textsearch.html), but it says something about *normalizing* before querying, and normalization is done through `to_tsvector`.

I created [this SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/3a14b/10) to demonstrate the two; here is the code if you don't want to navigate away:

**DDL**:

```
CREATE TABLE text (
  text_id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  source_text text NOT NULL,
  destination_text text NOT NULL
);
```

and the **SQL**:

```
-- Throw some stuff in there
INSERT INTO text (source_text, destination_text) VALUES
('Hello', 'Hello Result'),
('With Comma, Query', 'WithComma, Result');

-- Forced to use punctuation in the query to match what is in the vector
SELECT T.source_text, T.destination_text
FROM   text T
WHERE  LOWER(T.source_text)::tsvector @@ LOWER('Hello')::tsquery;

-- Vector free of punctuation, don't include it in the query
SELECT T.source_text, T.destination_text
FROM   text T
WHERE  to_tsvector(LOWER(T.source_text)) @@ LOWER('Comma')::tsquery;

SELECT ts_debug('english', 'Something without a comma');

SELECT ts_debug('english', 'Something, with a comma');
```

It seems to me that `to_tsvector` will take the text, strip it of punctuation and return the vector. On the other hand, `::tsvector` seems to include the punctuation in the vector, resulting in a need to use the same punctuation in the query.

What are the practical differences between the two? Is one generally preferred over the other? In what situations is each preferred?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`to_tsvector(text)` reads the string and does some normalization (taking language settings into account) on the string.

`::tsvector` is a cast. It does not do any normalization (and does not care for language settings).

See: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-textsearch.html

Some years ago a wrote an own to_tsvector() in python, since I was not happy with the way this was handled in postgres. This gave me more control.

To insert the data into the column I used the tsvector cast:

```
'UPDATE myapp_mymodel SET content=%s::tsvector where id=%s', [tsvector, self.id])
```

Comment: Ha, `::tsvector` is a *cast*... I get it now. That was not obvious to me in the documentation - I was using `::tsvector` early on in my project because I saw it widely used in examples, namely [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/datatype-textsearch.html). Thank you for the guidance!